# memcpy a pointer to a char buffer

Tags: c++, multithreading, job-scheduling

I am currently experimenting with some different implementations of a Job system (going based on [this](https://blog.molecular-matters.com/2015/08/24/job-system-2-0-lock-free-work-stealing-part-1-basics/) article).

The problem that I am trying to solve is the passing of arguments to a "Job function".

Here is my `Job` definition:

```
#define JOB_DATA_PADDING_SIZE   44

/** A job function is a function that can be worked on by the job manager */
typedef void( *JobFunction )( struct Job*, const void* );

/// <summary>
/// A job is something that represents work to be done by the thread pool.
/// Contains a pointer to it's work function and a counter to how many jobs
/// still need to be completed.
/// </summary>
struct Job
{
    JobFunction Function;                       // 8 byte
    Job* Parent;                                // 8 byte
    std::atomic<int32_t> UnfinishedJobs;        // 4 byte
    char Padding[ JOB_DATA_PADDING_SIZE ];      // 44 bytes, so that this object fills
                                                // a whole x64 cache line
};
```

As you can see, there is that `char Padding` buffer that needs to be there in order to avoid false sharing. I want to use that buffer as a way to simply store arguments that need to be passed in to whatever `JobFunction` the user is calling. This setup works well, with one exception: passing a pointer as an argument.

When the user goes to Create a job, they call this function on the `JobManager`:

```
Job * JobManager::CreateJob( JobFunction aFunction, void* args, size_t aSize )
{
    assert( aSize >= 0 && aSize < JOB_DATA_PADDING_SIZE );

    Job* job = AllocateJob();
    job->Function = aFunction;
    job->Parent = nullptr;
    job->UnfinishedJobs.store( 1 );

    // Memcpy the args to the jobs padding
    if ( args != nullptr )
    {
        memcpy( job->Padding, args, aSize );
    }

    return job;
}
```

As you can see, the plan is to simply `memcpy` the arguments that the user gives to the function into the `Padding`. This works for things like structs, and really any data that is less than that `44` byte size.

What I want to do is `memcpy` a given pointer *into* that `Padding` array. However, when I tried this I ran into the problem of `memcpy` copying the value at the pointer, and just copying that into the buffer.

Is there a way that I can `memcpy` the actual **pointer** into the buffer?

I have tried experimenting with `uint64_t` and `uintptr_t` but to no avail.

Is there a way to do this? Am I totally wrong about how this should work?

The whole project is on [GitHub](https://github.com/BenjaFriend/JobManager) if that helps to give more context as well.

Comment: `T* ptr; memcpy(job->padding, &ptr, sizeof ptr);` like that? `CreateJob(func, &ptr, sizeof ptr);` in this case.

Comment: How are you calling CrateJob? What is void* args? Is it a string?

Comment: If you are using that atomic as a cheap lock to prevent early execution, make sure all prep work is done before you set it to 1 (it should be the last thing in the function).

Comment: False sharing is only a problem if you're writing.   It doesn't seem like you'd be doing a lot of writing here, would you?  Also "This works for things like structs" - No it doesn't.  You can't then do a static_cast back into a "real" type - that's UB unless it's trivially copyable.  To memcpy a pointer, you give it a double pointer.

Comment: @xaxxon: It's not the memcpy that fails, you are allowed to inspect the bitwise representation of any object by memcpy-ing it into a char array, exactly like this function does.  It's when you try to use the result as anything besides inspection of the representation bits, that you quickly get into trouble.

Comment: @BenVoigt isn't that basically what I said?

Comment: @xaxxon: I guess I interpreted "This works for things like structs" to mean the call to memcpy, which does indeed work.  It sure could be useful for logging parameter values.  There definitely are difficulties with using the values inside the Job, you would need to have a job procedure designed to accept a copy of its arguments and copy them to objects of the correct types (which only works when they are trivially copyable).  In fact, you cannot `static_cast` and use the char array as if it were another type, not even if the types are trivially copyable (it violates strict aliasing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way that I can memcpy the actual pointer into the buffer?

Of course. Memcpy doesn't care what it's copying. All it does is copy bytes from a source location to a destination location.

Suppose you wanted to copy an `int` value.  Memcpy doesn't know about `int` values. It only knows about *locations*.  So you're going to have to put the value into some memory location (e.g., into an `int` *variable*), and then you can give memcpy a pointer to it.

```
extern void* destination_pointer;
int source = getIntValueFromWherever();          // put the value into the source location
size_t n_bytes = sizeof(source);
memcpy(destination_pointer, &source, n_bytes);   // then give memcpy a pointer to it.
```

But you wanted to copy a pointer.  Well, it's the same deal.  The thing that you want to copy (e.g., some `foobar_t*` pointer) has to be stored in a location (e.g., in a variable). Then you give memcpy pointers to the source and destination locations.

The only thing different from the `int` example above is the data type of the `source` variable:

```
extern void* destination_pointer;
foobar_t* source = getPointerFromWherever();     // put the value into the source location
size_t n_bytes = sizeof(source);
memcpy(destination_pointer, &source, n_bytes);   // then give memcpy a pointer to it.
```

Comment: Alright, this makes sense. Then how could I get that pointer back out of the `char` buffer to use it inside of one of my job functions?